# JVM on Rocky Linux 8 takes more CPU than CentOS 8

Tags: jvm, cpu, centos8, rocky-os

I migrated my Java server from CentOS 8 to Rocky Linux 8. the CPU usage is higher than before (on Cent OS 8).

### Here are the details of the top threads in the Java process on two operating systems:

## RockyLinux8

```
    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                           
 609746 root      20   0   15.5g   7.0g  31648 R   6.3  45.3   8:00.95 XNIO-1 task-2                                                                                                                     
 609758 root      20   0   15.5g   7.0g  31648 S   5.3  45.3   7:05.06 XNIO-1 task-9                                                                                                                     
 609464 root      20   0   15.5g   7.0g  31648 S   4.6  45.3  41:43.31 lettuce-nioEven                                                                                                                   
 609466 root      20   0   15.5g   7.0g  31648 S   4.6  45.3  38:27.62 lettuce-nioEven                                                                                                                   
 609468 root      20   0   15.5g   7.0g  31648 S   4.3  45.3  39:24.71 lettuce-nioEven                                                                                                                   
 618707 root      20   0   15.5g   7.0g  31648 S   3.6  45.3   0:11.44 XNIO-1 task-63                                                                                                                    
 611491 root      20   0   15.5g   7.0g  31648 S   3.3  45.3   0:56.47 XNIO-1 task-20                                                                                                                    
 609539 root      20   0   15.5g   7.0g  31648 S   2.3  45.3  19:00.52 XNIO-1 Accept                                                                                                                     
 609532 root      20   0   15.5g   7.0g  31648 S   1.3  45.3   7:29.97 XNIO-1 I/O-2                                                                                                                      
 609477 root      20   0   15.5g   7.0g  31648 S   1.0  45.3   8:22.03 kafka-producer-                                                                                                                   
 609480 root      20   0   15.5g   7.0g  31648 R   1.0  45.3   9:50.90 pool-2-thread-3                                                                                                                   
 609531 root      20   0   15.5g   7.0g  31648 S   1.0  45.3   7:22.77 XNIO-1 I/O-1                                                                                                                      
 609534 root      20   0   15.5g   7.0g  31648 S   1.0  45.3   7:23.73 XNIO-1 I/O-4                                                                                                                      
 609537 root      20   0   15.5g   7.0g  31648 S   1.0  45.3   7:21.69 XNIO-1 I/O-7
```

---

## CentOS8

```
    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                           
 252173 root      20   0   15.3g   8.7g  31736 S   3.3  55.8  33:33.07 XNIO-1 task-24                                                                                                                    
 258755 root      20   0   15.3g   8.7g  31736 S   2.7  55.8  13:13.16 XNIO-1 task-46                                                                                                                    
 247548 root      20   0   15.3g   8.7g  31736 S   2.3  55.8 327:41.01 lettuce-nioEven                                                                                                                   
 247552 root      20   0   15.3g   8.7g  31736 S   2.0  55.8 309:25.38 lettuce-nioEven                                                                                                                   
 252176 root      20   0   15.3g   8.7g  31736 S   2.0  55.8  19:04.62 XNIO-1 task-27                                                                                                                    
 247550 root      20   0   15.3g   8.7g  31736 S   1.7  55.8 297:43.67 lettuce-nioEven                                                                                                                   
 247562 root      20   0   15.3g   8.7g  31736 S   1.0  55.8  76:39.45 kafka-producer-                                                                                                                   
 252179 root      20   0   15.3g   8.7g  31736 S   1.0  55.8  29:18.36 XNIO-1 task-30                                                                                                                    
 247614 root      20   0   15.3g   8.7g  31736 S   0.7  55.8  55:41.29 XNIO-1 I/O-6                                                                                                                      
 247617 root      20   0   15.3g   8.7g  31736 S   0.7  55.8 135:45.15 XNIO-1 Accept                                                                                                                     
 247554 root      20   0   15.3g   8.7g  31736 S   0.3  55.8  42:02.05 SimplePauseDete                                                                                                                   
 247555 root      20   0   15.3g   8.7g  31736 S   0.3  55.8  41:23.20 SimplePauseDete                                                                                                                   
 247609 root      20   0   15.3g   8.7g  31736 S   0.3  55.8  55:42.72 XNIO-1 I/O-1                                                                                                                      
 247612 root      20   0   15.3g   8.7g  31736 S   0.3  55.8  56:02.54 XNIO-1 I/O-4                                                                                                                      
 247613 root      20   0   15.3g   8.7g  31736 S   0.3  55.8  55:57.00 XNIO-1 I/O-5                                                                                                                      
 247881 root      20   0   15.3g   8.7g  31736 S   0.3  55.8  17:13.01 XNIO-1 task-7                                                                                                                     
 489740 root      20   0   15.3g   8.7g  31736 S   0.3  55.8  35:56.69 pool-2-thread-1                                                                                                                   
 687519 root      20   0   15.3g   8.7g  31736 S   0.3  55.8   0:00.39 pool-2-thread-2                                                                                                                   
 689693 root      20   0   15.3g   8.7g  31736 S   0.3  55.8   0:00.02 pool-2-thread-2                                                                                                                   
 247518 root      20   0   15.3g   8.7g  31736 S   0.0  55.8   0:00.00 java                                                                                                                              
 247519 root      20   0   15.3g   8.7g  31736 S   0.0  55.8   0:07.04 java
 247520 root      20   0   15.3g   8.7g  31736 S   0.0  55.8   0:58.91 GC Thread#0
```

---

Have you ever been in this situation? Is there anything I can use to check why the JVM on RockyLinux8 is using more CPU than before?

Thank you for your help.